# Patch request using C# with HTTP client - Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, httpclient, microsoft-graph-api, patch

I have to do a patch request using the HTTP Client in C#.Seems very simple to do a Get request:

```
        var httpclient = GetHttpClient(accessToken.Result);
        var response = await 
        httpclient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
```

However for a patch, I cannot find a PatchAsync method, only seems to have POST and PUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace GetAsync with this in your code

```
var httpclient = GetHttpClient(accessToken.Result);
var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
```

Comment: Where would the httpcontent go?

Comment: @user8608110 please Check Edited answer.

Comment: Surely the content should go in the response variable ?

Comment: @MihirDave conde-only answers that don't explain what the code does or why it solves the problem are *not* considered good answers. *This* code is actually wrong - you forgot to add the content for the PATCH verb. Besides, adding yet another answer when there are good duplicates adds noise and makes it harder for the next person to find an answer

Comment: @user8608110 yes